# C# web service can't get environment variable value

Tags: c#, environment-variables

I'm getting no value back at all when trying to retrieve an environment variable in C#.  (I think this is a WCF web service - not a .NET expert) Here's my code:

```
string connectStr = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("TREP_Connect_String");

        m_logger.log(LogMsg.LOG_PRIORITY.DEBUG, MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name,
                        "Connection string: " + connectStr);

        var env = System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariables();

        string values = "";
        foreach(var item in env)
        {
            values += "; " + item;
        }

m_logger.log(LogMsg.LOG_PRIORITY.DEBUG, MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name,
                        "All environment variables: " + values);
```

The log:

```
Oct 10 08:47:59 DEBUG - Connection string:   
Oct 10 08:47:59 DEBUG - All environment variables: ;
```

So the problem isn't that I didn't set the environment variable in question, or misspelled it or something - it's not retrieving any environment variables at all, and obviously there are some set.  I'm using Visual Studio 2015 and the server is Windows Server 2012.  I have restarted the whole (virtual) machine since setting the variable.  This is running on Amazon EC2 if that matters.

Comment: What account is the service running as?

Comment: Did you look at the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/77zkk0b6(v=vs.110).aspx)? The default is to look under the context of the Process. If these are set under a user name then use the overload and specify the `EnvironmentVariableTarget`. You never mention under what context these should be found. Also it is usually recommended to save connection strings in the app.config (or web.config for web projects).

Comment: The application pool lists the "Identity" as "ApplicationPoolIdentity".  Not sure if that indicates a user.  I tried moving the variable to the system category rather than user.  I'm now getting some variables but not sure what they are because they're logged as `System.Collections.DictionaryEntry`.  The one I need is still blank.  And I'm doing this so the db connection string can be different on different servers without editing the config file.